# Difference between the use of "a" and "any" in these examples?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, difference

> I didn't have an idea.
>
> I did not have any idea.

I am much more familiar with the second one. The first one sounds a bit odd to me, but sounds fine if I say:

> I did not have even an idea.

But, the first one is also one of the widely used sentences by natives. What is the difference between the two?

Comment: When **did** is used as a helper verb to form the past tense, it is in combination with the bare infinitive, not with a tensed form of the verb. So, "I didn't **have** a coin".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I did not have an idea** = I was asked to contribute an idea but I was unable to  think of one; an idea did not come into my head in some situation where an idea was expected from me.

**I had no idea** =  I was unable to *explain* something; it was a mystery to me or it was something about which I had no knowledge whatsoever.

**I did not have any idea** = I had no idea.