# Difference between "a" and "any"

Tags: difference, indefinite-article, determiners

what is difference between the two following sentences? And which one is grammatical?

1- If there is ***a*** car in the garden, it will be towed away.

2- If there is ***any***  car in the garden, it will be towed away.

Please note that I am making a general statement and thinking of just one car.

Comment: Related: [Difference between the use of “a” and “any” in these examples?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/113408/)

Comment: No, not any. If there is any coffee in the garden, it will be removed.

Answer (score 1):

"a" is an article meaning "***one*** of something":

> I have **one** book; therefore, I have **a** book.

"any" is an adjective meaning "***some***, no matter how many or how few there may be".  It is often used in questions:

> Are there **any** books in your bag? (Question)
>
> Yes, there are **some** books in my bag. (Answer)

It is also used in statements to replace the adjective "some" in negative statements:

> I haven't **any** money in my pocket. (negated: *haven't = have
>   **not***)
>
> I have **some** money in my pocket. (positive)

I hope this might have helped you out.  Should you have **any** more questions, feel free to ask and I shall try to answer.  Take care and good luck!

Comment: Thank you Nick, your answer is great. So are both the above sentences correct?

Comment: @user256007, both are not correct. see my answer

Comment: Yes, your examples are fine. Using "were" and "would", rather than what you've used above, makes the statement contrary to fact in the present. Using "was" is not correct in Kailash's example above; however, it is such a common error among native speakers that I am not going to belabor it right now.

Comment: Sorry, but your answer is correct but this sentence:  "If there is any  car in the garden, it will be towed away". is not. Nick's own answer says: any books with an s. The OP's question would therefore have to be: any cars with an s. "Is there any car" is not grammatical. **Are there any cars in the garden?**